# "How to fix 'uses or overrides a deprecated API and Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details' in Java"

Tags: java, linux, hadoop

I want to take advantage of using linux to practice examples of Hadoop-MapReduce.
I have written a code for my project and I am getting some warning message when I compile. I could not run it. Having tried many possible ways like ignoring warning and etc, I am still unable to run it. Below you will find the code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
importorg.apache.hadoop.filecache.DistributedCache;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils;
```

```
public class Average{
  public static class Map extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
   public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  String line = value.toString();
  StringTokenizer script = new StringTokenizer(line, "\n");  while (script.hasMoreTokens()) {
   StringTokenizer scriptLine = new StringTokenizer(script.nextToken());
   Text Name = new Text(scriptLine.nextToken());
   int Score = Integer.parseInt(scriptLine.nextToken());
   context.write(Name, new IntWritable(Score));
  }
 }
}

  public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
  public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
     int numerator = 0;
   int denominator = 0;
   int avg = 0;
   for (IntWritable score : value) {
    numerator += score.get();
    denominator++;
   }
   avg = numerator/denominator; 
   context.write(key, new IntWritable(avg));
         }
 }

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

   Configuration conf = new Configuration();
   String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
         Path dst_path = new Path (otherArgs[1]);
         FileSystem hdfs = dst_path.getFileSystem(conf);

         if (hdfs.exists(dst_path)){
          hdfs.delete(dst_path, true);
         };

            Job job = new Job(conf, "Average");
            job.setJarByClass(Average.class);
            job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
            job.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
            job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));

            System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
         }
}
```

Comment: by not using deprecated stuff. Deprecated means : This is old, this is no longer maintained, corrections to the code won't be applied here, but in the code that replaces this. For instance, don't use StringTokenizer, use the split method of String instead. StringTokenizer has been deprecated for quite a few years.

Comment: have you tried using @suppresswarnings("deprecation")?

Comment: This warning is not the cause of your error.